# ngx-color-picker is being closed on input change

Tags: angular, angular-material, color-picker

I'm using ngx-color-picker in my angular 6 project, it is working on my project component HTML. but when I try to use the picker on mat-menu, the color picker  is being closed while changing the input. It's not giving any error. the color is being selected successfully but while typing color value in color picker input it is being closed. I don't know why. Here is my code.

```
<div class="d-flex mb-2" *ngFor="let clr of gradientArray; let i = index;">
   <input class="form-control" [cpPosition]="'right'" [cpOutputFormat]="'hex'" [(colorPicker)]="clr.color" [style.background]="clr.color" (cpSliderDragEnd)="changeGradientColor(clr.color, i)">
</div>
```

Comment: I think material is override ` ngx-color-picker` property. please provide code .

Comment: Added code, Please check.

Comment: where you have to use `mat-menu`?

Comment: check this link. you want to do like this? [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7vj8e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Yes, I want to do like this but it's not working properly.

Comment: i will update my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it worked myself, Just added trackBy.

```
<div class="d-flex mb-2" *ngFor="let clr of gradientArray; let i = index; trackBy: trackBgGradient">
   <input class="form-control" [cpPosition]="'right'" [cpOutputFormat]="'hex'" [(colorPicker)]="clr.color" [style.background]="clr.color" (cpSliderDragEnd)="changeGradientColor(clr.color, i)">
</div>
```

Comment: beyond the shadow of a doubt, it's very clearly explained Thank you

Comment: This is really helpful for me. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

this is working code try:

HTML:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (click)="openMyMenu()">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" overlapTrigger="false">
  <span (mouseleave)="closeMyMenu()">
    <input *ngFor="let clr of gradientArray; let i = index;" mat-menu-item [cpPosition]="'right'" [cpOutputFormat]="'hex'" [(colorPicker)]="clr.color" [style.background]="clr.color" (cpSliderDragEnd)="changeGradientColor(clr.color, i)" (click) = "$event.stopPropagation()">
  </span>
</mat-menu>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;
  gradientArray: any[] = [
    {color: 'red'},
     {color: 'blue'},
      {color: 'green'},
       {color: 'yellow'},
        {color: 'black'},
  ];
```

Also check on stackblitz link: `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7vj8e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts`